# Difference between Array#map and Enumerable#map

Tags: arrays, ruby

Ruby's built-in class Array defines a method `map`: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-map

Ruby's built-in module Enumerable also defines a method `map`: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map

The Enumerable module is attached to the Array class, so why would this method be defined in Array if it is implemented by Enumerable anyway?

Comment: Performance reasons. `Enumerable` doesn't know the array's final size (it starts with an empty array) and has the overhead of invoking `each`. `Array` on the other hand does know the final size and can iterate the elements without any overhead. I'm pretty sure this has been asked (and answered in depth) before.

Comment: I searched SO, Google and the docs for an answer and found nothing. If you can find a duplicate that I couldn't, be my guest #SOreadytohelp